# canWrite method on file

Tags: java

I wanted to know if canWrite() method of File class can be used to test directory path like below?

```
String filePath = "\\folder1\\folder2\\subfolder1\\actualfolder\\";

File f = new File(filePath);

if(f.exists()){
boolean wStatus  =  f.canWrite();
boolean rStatus  =  f.canRead();

}
```

**here I wanted to check if the folder "actualfolder" is writable or not. Do I need to go back to a folder back and test it or simply can I check using method canWrite()?**

I am supposed to use currently Jdk1.6 and not supposed to create a file and then delete under that folder to verify if the directory is writable

Comment: "public boolean canWrite()

Tests whether the application can modify the file denoted by this abstract pathname." ???

Comment: what is abstract pathname?

Comment: you want to test if the directory exists?

Comment: i wanted to test exact path that I have posted . here i wanted to check if the folder "actualfolder" is writable. do I need to go back to a folder back and test it or simply can I check canWrite?

Comment: If you want reliable file metadata attribute detection, use the `Files` API from Java 7+. `File`'s `.can*()` fail to work properly under Windows for instance.

Comment: I am supposed to use currently Jdk1.6 and not supposed to create a file and then delete under that folder to verify if the directory is writable

Comment: Why do you have to use JDK1.6? Even 7 has been moved on from.